# Joining 2 tables by latest date

Tags: sql, oracle

2 tables

select * from general_data

```
 ID  | currecny | DATE_ACT
  1       USD    01/12/2015    
  2       USD    02/12/2015 
  3       GBP    01/12/2015
  4       GBP    03/12/2015 
  5       USD    06/12/2015
```

select * from currency_data

```
  currecny | RATE_DATE | Rate
    USD      04/12/2015   3.51
    USD      02/12/2015   3.46
    GBP      01/12/2015   4.62
    USD      01/12/2015   3.50
```

I want to match ID to it's valid currency.

Currency is matched by currency name, and 'date'.
 --if there is no such date in 'currency_data' table, it should be matched   to   previous date.

So desired output:

```
 ID  | rate | 
  1    3.50      
  2    3.46   
  3    4.62   
  4    4.62    
  5    3.51
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT gd.ID,
       (SELECT rate
          FROM currency_data cd
         WHERE cd.currecny = gd.currecny
           AND gd.date_act >= cd.rate_date
           AND ROWNUM = 1
           order by  cd.rate_date) rate
  FROM general_data gd
  order by 1
```

Getting syntax error on order by, but I need order to get the latest.

Comment: The `order by` is useless, because the `rownum` is processed before it.  However, I don't think it would generate an error.

Comment: I don't think you can use `order by` in a subquery, without selecting `top x`

Comment: @HoneyBadger . . . Oracle doesn't support `TOP` and `ORDER BY` is regularly used in queries with `rownum` in the outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, ah right, got my dbms's confused, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain to do in Oracle.  In Oracle 12g, you can use `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT gd.ID,
       (SELECT rate
        FROM currency_data cd
        WHERE cd.currecny = gd.currecny AND
              gd.date_act >= cd.rate_date
        ORDER BY cd.rate_date
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) rate
FROM general_data gd
ORDER BY 1;
```

But that only works with the most recent release.  Unfortunately, using two subqueries to use `rownum` is problematic, because Oracle's scoping rules do not allow nested correlations.

But, there is a solution:

```
SELECT gd.ID,
       (SELECT MAX(rate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cd.rate_date)
        FROM currency_data cd
        WHERE cd.currecny = gd.currecny AND
              gd.date_act >= cd.rate_date
       ) rate
FROM general_data gd
ORDER BY 1;
```

`KEEP` to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT gd.ID, cd.Rate
FROM general_data gd
LEFT OUTER JOIN currency_data cd
ON cd.currency = gd.currency
AND cd.rate_date =
(
SELECT max(rate_date) 
FROM currency_data cd
WHERE cd.currency = gd.currency
AND cd.rate_date <= gd.date_act
)
ORDER BY 1
```

[Try it on SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b07fd/4/0)

Comment: Well this looks good, just want some confirmation that nothing was missed  (some specfic scenario )

Comment: Use the SQLFIDDLE link to try other cases.  You did not state how the special cases where no currency or date exists are to be handled.